# Lumen/Laravel model attributes not included in serialisation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, eloquent

I have defined an Eloquent model `Image` including something like this:

```
public function getThumbnailAttribute() {
  return $this->id . '.jpg';
}
```

I am fetching the data with a query like this:

```
Image::query();
$query->selectRaw('images.*');
$query->join('paths', 'images.id', '=', 'paths.image_id');
$query->where('paths.path', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('text') . '%');
$return = $query->get();
```

I can access `$return[0]->thumbnail` fine, but in the `$return` array that attribute is not present. The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization) seem to suggest that it would be, unless `$hidden` or `$visible` is set, which they were not, and I've tried setting `$hidden` to an empty array, too.

I am new to Eloquent, so I've clearly got something wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have `thumbnail` column in your migration? if you are creating a virtual attribute (faking a model attribute using mutators) then i can suggest you the fix?

Comment: You need to define an `appends` array on your model -
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: @fubar Yes that was it, thanks.